# Functional composition using for-comprehension results in Char instead of String

Tags: string, scala, functional-programming, function-composition, for-comprehension

I was trying to use for comprehension to structure my object calls and here is my simple implementation:

```
object FuncA extends (String => Int => String) {
    override def apply(str: String): Int => String = i => {
      s"${(str.toInt + i).toString}"
    }
  }

  object FuncB extends (String => Int) {
    override def apply(str: String): Int = {
      str.toInt
    }
  }

  for {
    funcAStr <- FuncA("1")(1)
    funcBStr <- FuncB(funcAStr) // Fails here
  } yield {
    println(s"Final String incremented as int is $funcBStr")
  }
```

But strangely I have a problem where the funcAStr is being interpreted as a Char instead of a String. Any ideal why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the inclusion of the `for-loop` tag, `for` in Scala does not define a loop. `for` is a shorthand way of defining a sequence of `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter` calls.

Your code translates to this:

```
FuncA("1")(1).flatMap{ funcAStr =>
  FuncB(funcAStr).map{ funcBStr =>
    println(s"Final String incremented as int is $funcBStr")
  }
}
```

`Func("1")(1)` returns `String`. The `flatMap` method on `String` takes each character of the string in turn, so `funcAStr` is actually `Char` not `String`.

Answer (score 5):

Try functional composition using `andThen` like so

```
(FuncA("1") andThen FuncB)(1)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Int = 2
```

Comment: I can do this, but I want to stick with for comprehensions as I have a lot of those functional objects that I would want to compose!

Answer (score 3):

In Scala *for-comprehension* is just syntactic sugar over nested calls of `flatMap`  ,`map` or `foreach`. Simplifying, the basic rule is that every arrow will translate to nested `flatMap` and the last arrow will translate to either `map` or `foreach` depending on if you used `yield` or not.

In your case *for-comprehension* will translate to something similar to:

```
val r: Seq[Unit] = 
    FuncA("1")(1).flatMap{ funcAStr : Char =>
       FuncB(funcAStr).map{ funcBStr: Int =>
           println(s"Final String incremented as int is $funcBStr")
       }
    }
```

And it doesn't really make much sense since first of all `funcBStr` expects `String` not `Char`. But even if you fixed it, then the compiler would complain, because `flatMap` would expect something which can be represented as `GenTraversableOnce[B]`.

So I guess you shouldn't use *for-comprehension* at all in your use case.

If you're using IntelliJ, you can use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which will show *Desugar Scala Code* dialog. Then you will be able to select *expand for comprehensions* and show you how do your *for-comprehension* translates to `flatMap`/`map` calls.